# asp.net mvc and routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following Actions in Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pageNumber)
public ActionResult Details(string seoFriendlyName)
```

And I want to have the following routes:

```
~/article/ -> Action = Index, pageNumber = 1
~/article/page-5 -> Action = Index, pageNumber = 5
~/article/page-1 -> ~/article/
~/article/foo -> Action = Details, seoFriendlyName = foo
```

I've tried to define the following routes, but it doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article/page-{pageNumber}",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", pageNumber = 1 },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article/{seoFriendlyName}",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Details", },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are self-contradictory. For example, what route should be selected if you have an article with seoFriendlyName == "page-6" and actual pageNumber == 2?

I'd suggest you change your requirements to

```
~/article/ -> Action = Index, pageNumber = 1
~/article/page/5 -> Action = Index, pageNumber = 5
~/article/page/1 -> ~/article/
~/article/foo -> Action = Details, seoFriendlyName = foo
```

and then you will have the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article/page/{pageNumber}",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", pageNumber = 1 },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article/{seoFriendlyName}",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Details", },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);
```

**UPDATE**

In response to comments:

for that specific requirement you'll need to modify your routes that way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", pageNumber = 1 },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article/page/{pageNumber}",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);


routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "article/{seoFriendlyName}",
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Details", },
                new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);
```

Comment: If I call `Url.Action("Index", "MyController")` then `~/article/page` will be rendered instead of `~/article`

Comment: If you want this to be `~/article` then you'll need to change routes order. Also, as Jan suggested, you should move your default pageNumer setting to another route. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You havn't told us, whats exactly not working.
The only thing i have seen is, that you set wrong values to your pageNumber parameter.

This should work better:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "article",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", pageNumber = 1 },
    new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "article/page-{pageNumber}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index"},
    new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "article/{seoFriendlyName}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Details" },
    new[] { "MyNamespace" }
);
```

Comment: In your sample, if I call `Url.Action("Index", "MyController", new { pageNumber = 1 })` that will be rendered as `~/article/page-1` and I want it to be rendered as `~/article`

Comment: Yes, change the order of the first to routes.